# What are some top reasons to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010? (while staying with .NET 3.5)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Beside IntelliTrace, what are some top reasons to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the compelling reason to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 from VS2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885955/whats-the-compelling-reason-to-upgrade-to-visual-studio-2010-from-vs2008)

Answer (score 5):

- Improved designer support for WPF
- Improved IDE experience (for example, adding references is much faster).
- Architecture tools (class diagram, sequence diagram, diagram enforcement, etc).
- Support for multiple monitors.

Comment: I personally feel like VS2010 is a much better experience than previous versions.  Super slim tool window borders, great multi-screen support, and oh I don't have to wait for Add References anymore.

Comment: Yes, to me it also seems faster, when debugging large projects.
You can even copy References from project to project, with the power tools from Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I'de say better multiscreen support.

Answer (score 1):

Tools Echo System

Visual Studio 2010 introduced a brand new extension story and a new WPF editor.  It greatly reduced the barriers for building extensions and increased the expressiveness of such extensions.  The result is a slew of new extensions for Visual Studio that provide a lot of the missing or desired functionality.

The extensions are available through the Extension Manager in Visual Studio and can additionally be searched online on the Visual Studio gallery.

- http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/

This is the app store for Visual Studio with mostly free extensions.

IMHO, this is the #1 reason to upgrade to 2010.

Answer (score 1):

- New features, like improved intellisense support
- IntelliTrace
- Improved debug power, for example you can pin tooltips to screen while you are debugging.
- Best integration for Visual Studio ALM
- Of course multi monitor support
- More friendly WPF designer, for example at vs 2008 if you are trying to open a user control's xaml document as Design mode in class library project; you can not. But at vs 2010 you can.

Answer (score 0):

- Enables future development against .NET 4.0
- Allows access to new versions of build tools

Answer (score 0):

If you edit XAML/WPF-Forms a lot, then you will enjoy working with VS2010 instead of VS2008. It is more "Blend" like.
There is also some nice Plug-In from Karl Shifflet [XAML power toys](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/xaml-power-toys/#Overview)

Answer (score 0):

1. [Debugger](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/21/vs-2010-debugger-improvements-breakpoints-datatips-import-export.aspx)
2. [IDE Improvements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547188.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Named/Optional parameters for C#.  You can use them while targeting 3.5 because 2.0 IL allows it so the new compiler can use it.